# Let X be a random variable with density f(x) = e^−(x+2) for x > −2, and f(x)=0 otherwise. Find the moment generating function of X, E[X] and E[X^2].

Tags: probability

As f(x)=e$^-$$^($$^x$$^+$$^2$$^)$ hence P(x)=-e$^-$$^($$^x$$^+$$^2$$^)$ hence shouldn't M(t) the integral from infinity to minus infinity of e$^t$$^x$.-e$^-$$^($$^x$$^+$$^2$$^)$, is this true? How do I find E[X] and E[X$^2$] from there?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @sudeep5221 I have tried evaluating the moment generating function, however the integral is seemingly very hard to integrate with the inclusion of e$^t$ within the equation, hence the question, is it true?

Comment: You are on the correct track. The resulting integral is $\int_0^{\infty} e^{tx} e^{-x-2} \ dx = e^{-2} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-(1- t)x} \ dx$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @sudeep5221 I think the lower bounds on your integrals should be $-2$, not $0$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the moment-generating function of $X$ is
\begin{align}
M_X(t) &:= \mathbb E[e^{t X}]\\
&= \int_{\mathbb R} e^{t x}f_X(x)\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \int_{-2}^\infty e^{t x}e^{-(x+2)}\ \mathsf dx\\
&= e^{-2}\int_{-2}^\infty e^{-(1-t)x}\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \frac{e^{-2t}}{1-t},\quad t<1.
\end{align}
We can compute the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ moment of $X$ by
$$
\mathbb E[X^n] = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\mathsf d^n}{\mathsf dt^n}M_X(t).
$$
In this case,
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\mathsf d^n}{\mathsf dt^n}\left[\frac{e^{-2t}}{1-t}\right] = e^{-2}\cdot\Gamma(n+1, -2),
$$
where $\Gamma(a,z)$ denotes the incomplete gamma function:
$$
\Gamma(a,z) := \int_z^\infty s^{a-1}e^{-s}\ \mathsf ds.
$$
In particular for $n=1$ and $n=2$ this yields
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X] &= -1\\
\mathbb E[X^2] &= 2.
\end{align}